# Should we go out of our way to help someone , when it is not our duty?

Tags: dharma

People get fruits of their karma. So,Should we go out of ways to help when we see someone is suffering or in some bad situation (i.e. getting punished for their bad karma) ?

I am asking about situation when it is not our duty or dharma to help that person. And we will not be deemed as guilty for not helping the person.

What does Shastras say about this ?